# Regex for alphanumeric and the + character

Tags: c#, regex

I need a regex that allows only alphanumeric plus the + and - character.

Right now I am using:

```
[^\w-]
```

Comment: Is é "alphanumeric" ? What about ø ? What about ٣ ?

Answer (score 10):

The following pattern will match strings that contain only letters, digits, '+' or '-', including international characters such as 'å' or 'ö' (and excluding the '_' character that is included in '`\w`'):

```
^[-+\p{L}\p{N}]+$
```

Examples:

```
string pattern = @"^[-+\p{L}\p{N}]+$";
Regex.IsMatch("abc", pattern); // returns true
Regex.IsMatch("abc123", pattern); // returns true
Regex.IsMatch("abc123+-", pattern); // returns true
Regex.IsMatch("abc123+-åäö", pattern); // returns true
Regex.IsMatch("abc123_", pattern); // returns false
Regex.IsMatch("abc123+-?", pattern); // returns false
Regex.IsMatch("abc123+-|", pattern); // returns false
```

Comment: Bummer ;o) forgot to exclude the underscore... There is always something you overlook when dealing with regex.

Comment: There, did some homework. Hopefully there are no other hidden suprises now.

Comment: @Blixt: yes, I like supporting international characters. Comes with being non-English perhaps. Thanks for pointing out the underscore issue, btw.

Comment: Of course, I'm Swedish too `=)` I just like the principle of starting with a limited solution, and extending it as the need arises (of course, the OP might very well want to support international characters from the start.) You could probably say I'm talking about the same thing as the *YAGNI* principle (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAGNI)

Answer (score 4):

This regular expression will match only if you test it against a string that has alphanumeric characters and/or `+`/`-`:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9\-+]+$
```

To use it:

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(input, @"^[a-zA-Z0-9\-+]+$"))
{
    // String only contains the characters you want.
}
```

Comment: I always feel that "0-9" is better expressed as "\d". +1, because this is the most complete answer yet.

Comment: @Fredrik: True, it does of course depend on which language it's for. Using `\w` isn't correct either though, due to the fact that it includes the `_` character.

Comment: @Cerebrus: Yeah, I guess that's nice too, although I like the explicity of `0-9`. I mostly use `\d` when I only want to match `0-9` outside of a character class, because it's much more concise than `[0-9]`. Inside a character class, there's only a one character difference.

Comment: There's more of a difference than that. .NET's `\d` is the same as `\p{Nd}`, which matches a lot more than `[0-9]` (but you can change that with the `RegexOptions.ECMAScript` modifier).

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
[a-zA-Z0-9+\-]
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to escape the - char: `[\w\-+]` for single character and `[\w\-+]+` for more.

Comment: That will allow for non-alphanumerics as well; it only indicates that there are alpanumerics and '+' or '-' in the string, but does not exclude other characters.

Comment: No you don't, just put the "-" first

Comment: Putting special characters first/last works, but it's worth showing explicitly that it's a special character, so that it doesn't accidentally "activate" when the pattern is modified.

Answer (score 1):

[a-zA-Z0-9\+\-]

Answer (score 1):

Matches single -, + or alpha-numeric:

```
[-+a-zA-Z0-9]
```

Matches any number of -, + or alpha-numeric:

```
[-+a-zA-Z0-9]*
```

Matches a string/line of just -, + or alpha-numeric:

```
^[-+a-zA-Z0-9]*$
```